# Parsing html string to DOM Element: Issue with anchor Tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have been trying to parse html string to DOM nodes and i keep having the same issue with the anchor links irrespective of the approach i use,

Here is the html string for testing:

```
let htmlString = '<div><h2>Absolute URLs</h2><p><a href="https://www.w3.org/">W3C</a></p><p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></p><h2>Relative URLs</h2><p><a href="html_images.asp">HTML Images</a></p><p><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS Tutorial</a></p></div>';
```

and i try to parse by the following methods and i get the same output, not sure how to resolve this,

```
let template = document.createElement('template');
htmlString = htmlString.trim();
template.innerHTML = htmlString;
  
console.log(template.content.firstChild);
```

```
let docs = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString,'text/html');
console.log(docs.body.firstChild);
```

The converted DOM is following where you can see that the slashes in the anchor tags are getting replaced with empty character and href is repeated in the closing anchor tag, its with all the anchor tags

```
<div><h2>Absolute&nbsp;URLs</h2><p><a href="https: www.w3.org="" "="">W3C</a href="https:></p><p><a href="https: www.google.com="" "="">Google</a href="https:></p><h2>Relative&nbsp;URLs</h2><p><a href="html_images.asp">HTML&nbsp;Images</a href="html_images.asp"></p><p><a href=" css="" default.asp"="">CSS&nbsp;Tutorial</a href="></p></div>
```

any help to how to go about it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm not able to reproduce this on the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, and Edge

Comment: i am using latest version of chrome, i also tried it in codepen before posting it here.

Comment: [I tried it in codepen](https://codepen.io/grimsteel/pen/YzOOwoL?editors=0012) and it works for me. Do have any other code that might be altering the output?

Comment: Here is my [codepen link](https://codepen.io/shaklin-syed/pen/QWVdady?editors=1010) where it is still the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do this:

```
let template = document.createElement('template');
```

You can just have in your HTML something to put your stuff in like:

```
<div id="myContainer"></div>
```

And then:

```
document.getElementById("myContainer").innerHTML = htmlString;
```

This its how I use to do it and it works.

You can also add your anchor empty and then add the data via JS.

Comment: Irrespective of the element we create the output is still the same. The anchor tags are breaking.

Comment: Try replacing '/' by '\/'. This way the character should appear. Maybe the problem is DOMparser or the character encode, try my example without parsing and check your encoding.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your Codepen, it looks like the issue is that all of the spaces in `htmlString` are non breaking spaces. (that's why you see the `&nbsp;` in the output)

Stack Overflow must have replaced these with normal spaces, which was why we couldn't reproduce the issue at first.

To solve it, use the [`String#normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) method:

```js
let docs = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString.normalize('NFKD'),'text/html');
```

You could also manually replace all of the non breaking spaces (`\xa0`) with normal spaces:

```js
let docs = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString.replace(/\xa0/g, ' '),'text/html');

// You can also use replaceAll
let docs = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString.replaceAll('\xa0', ' '),'text/html');
```